# Proper formula for computing signal-to-noise ratio of a camera?

Tags: remote-sensing, noise

I have a 5-band muultispectral camera, and I'm trying to find the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) to supplement some research data I collected. Cameras with low SNRs generally have lower-quality images due to sensor sizes.

According to a formula I found on Axis communications, the SNR can be computed by taking the 20(log10) of the ratio of the mean pixel values of a given area to the standard deviation of the same pixel values, of a homogeneous image. The formula is as follows:

[image]

where µR µG µB is the mean pixel value of the red, green, and blue bands, respectively, and the denominator is the variance of the red, green, and blue bands, respectively. (Note: My camera has 5 bands, so I would just add the two additional bands to the RGB bands).

However, according to Lu and He (2017), the SNR can be computed by simply taking the ratio of the mean pixel values to the standard deviation. Apparently, there is no log 10 calculation according to this source.

**Which method is the correct way to find the SNR of a camera?**

Source:
Lu B, He Y (2017) Species classification using Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV)-acquired high spatial resolution imagery in a heterogeneous grassland. ISPRS Journal of Photogrammetry and Remote Sensing 128:73-85